# Can't find /root/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, centos, composer-php, virtualbox, adminlte

I have installed composer on Centos 7 virtualbox with PHP 5.6.27. I will show the commands that I have used and the issues that I am now having. I should first say that all of these commands have worked on previous installations.

Okay so for starters here is what I used to install composer.

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Followed by

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Now I am trying to install laravel via the commands listed below.

```
composer global require "acacha/adminlte-laravel-installer=~3.0"
```

Up to this point all of the commands listed above have successfully worked.

Now here is the current problem. When I try to run the following command I get an error.

```
laravel new laravel-with-admin-lte
-bash: /root/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel: No such file or directory.
```

I have tried a whole set of remedies for this message but it cannot find the .composer directory. Can anyone tell me where the correct .composer directory is and how I can modify it so that it looks to the proper location to finalize this installation?

I appreciate any solutions that you can provide me. I have struggled with this for two days straight and have googled everything under the sun. Hopefully, someone on here has had a similar solution with a valid resolution.

Comment: composer create-project laravel/laravel blog; works just for a heads up. I need the laravel new blog to work in this specific scenario.

Comment: did you do "admilte-laravel install"?

Comment: Yes, the command operates but fails because laravel has not been installed. It is looking for artisan app.php and can not find it in the directory due to the fact that laravel is not there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

download as superuser

## download installer

```
sudo composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

## setting up path

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

## check laravel command

```
laravel
```

Comment: Never run composer globally. The terminal will even scream at you if you try to install composer globally. You can read more here: 
https://www.sitepoint.com/composer-global-require-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 9):

Put an alias to the freshly installed Laravel installer in your user configuration .bashrc:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

And place this inside the file:

```
alias laravel='~/.config/composer/vendor/bin/laravel'
```

And run the following to make sure your bashrc profile is reloaded:

```
source ~/.bashrc
laravel new project
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed (Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I changed the directory.

This is the directory where your bash was created: /root/.config/composer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYQqE.png)

but when excute the laravel command, the system search en the directory : bash: /root/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8u37.png)

So, just you need to change the address /root/.config/composer/vendor to /root/.composer/vendor.

PD. sorry I am learning english, so it is a little bad.